# Нужен скрипт на T-SQL для одновременного создания двух запросов к одному столбцу

Tags: sql, запрос

У меня есть задача, решение которой я не могу найти на просторах интернета и потому решил обратиться к профессионалам.

*Описание ситуации:*

Есть SQL таблица под названием "Общая" в которую в режиме реального времени каждую секунду добавляется строка (это условно, может и на много больше строк, даже и несколько десятков). Таблица имеет следующие столбцы "Номер", "Наименование", "Кол-во", "Действие". Все столбцы кроме одного имеют различные значения, но столбец "Действие" имеет только два значения "купля" и "продажа".

*Задача:* необходимо произвести в режиме реального времени сортировку столбца "Действие" по параметрам купля/продажа и вывести отсортированные строки в разные таблицы с соответствующими названиями "Купля" и "Продажа".

Вот эти 2 запроса:

```
1 -SELECT TOP (1000000) * 
  FROM [myLocalDB].[dbo].[Общая]
  WHERE Действие = 'продажа'

2 -SELECT TOP (1000000) * 
  FROM [myLocalDB].[dbo].[Общая]
  WHERE Действие = 'купля'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql

Comment: Спасибо, а есть готовые примеры именно под мой запрос, а то я новичок, пока не получается составить самому (((                            

P.S. не надо выводить в разные таблицы, нужен просто запрос к одной колонке с выводом результатов в окне.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.

Вот ответ на мой вопрос. Запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT 
BuyTbl.[Кол-во] AS Buy 
,SellTbl.[Кол-во] AS Sell  
FROM 
--получаем сумму по купле 
(SELECT 
SUM([Кол-во]) AS [Кол-во] 
—,[Действие] 
FROM [Общая] 
WHERE [Действие] = 'Купля' 
GROUP BY [Действие]) BuyTbl 
--получаем сумму по продаже 
,(SELECT 
SUM([Кол-во]) AS [Кол-во] 
—,[Действие] 
FROM [Общая] 
WHERE [Действие] = 'Продажа' 
GROUP BY [Действие]) SellTbl
```